# Generate a stack of Polaroid-like photos from existing images using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I would like to be able to take 5 JPG images and process them with ImageMagick to create an effect showing the photos as a stack of Polaroid-like prints.

Assuming all photos are the same aspect ratio, they need to be resized to the same size, a 10px Polaroid-like border applied, then all slightly rotated and offset such that images below the top one are partially visible around the edges.

The rotation/offset doesn't need to be random as such - it could be hand-coded for each image in the stack if it is easier than doing it truly random?

Here is an example of the effect I am aiming for: [image: Stack of Polaroid-like photos]

Can someone help with the correct parameters to use - I'm assuming we would want to use convert?

Edit: I already knew about the example contained on the ImageMagick page, but it doesn't specifically address my requirements - they clone the original image, they don't use multiple separate images. They also don't do a great job of explaining in each example exactly what every option does - they assume you already have spent hours (or days!) experimenting with the millions of options available. A bit difficult for someone who has never used the tool to master without a lot of work.

```
convert thumbnail.gif \
    -bordercolor white  -border 6 \
    -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 \
    -bordercolor none  -background  none \
    \( -clone 0 -rotate `convert null: -format '%[fx:rand()*30-15]' info:` \) \
    \( -clone 0 -rotate `convert null: -format '%[fx:rand()*30-15]' info:` \) \
    \( -clone 0 -rotate `convert null: -format '%[fx:rand()*30-15]' info:` \) \
    \( -clone 0 -rotate `convert null: -format '%[fx:rand()*30-15]' info:` \) \
    -delete 0  -border 100x80  -gravity center \
    -crop 200x160+0+0  +repage  -flatten  -trim +repage \
    -background black \( +clone -shadow 60x4+4+4 \) +swap \
    -background none  -flatten \
    poloroid_stack.png
```

... it would be great if someone could expand on this example and show me how to modify it to achieve my desired results as above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the command I found to give a pretty good result for what I needed - thanks to @Jim Lindstrom for putting me on the right track.

```
convert \
    img-5.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
    -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
    -background none -rotate -4 \
    \
    \( img-2.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate 6 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-3.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate -2 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-1.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate -4 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-4.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate 4 \
    \) \
    \
    -border 100x80 -gravity center +repage -flatten -trim +repage \
    -background black \( +clone -shadow 60x4+4+4 \) +swap -background none \
    -flatten stack.png
```

Here is the output I get from my images using the above command:

[image: Polaroid Stack]

It's not perfect yet, I have some more tweaks I'd like to do which I'll ask about in a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for "convert" show almost exactly how. Search for "nice looking pile of photos" on http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#polaroid

Here's another way of doing it that makes, hopefully, clearer how one would sub in their own photos:

```
# create four images we want to use as our polaroid stack (I'm using the same one for all
# one, but you don't have to)
curl -O http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/thumbnail.gif
cp thumbnail.gif thumbnail1.gif
cp thumbnail.gif thumbnail2.gif
cp thumbnail.gif thumbnail3.gif
cp thumbnail.gif thumbnail4.gif
rm thumbnail.gif

# You can easily see the recurring portion of this command. You could build 
# it up programmatically and then execute it, for however many images you want.
# I've also simplified the example in their docs by hard-coding some rotation
# angles. Feel free to get fancy, or just hard code an array of them and keep
# grabbing the next one.
convert \
   thumbnail1.gif \
   -bordercolor white  -border 6 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 \
   -bordercolor none  -background  none \
   -rotate 20  \
   -trim +repage \
   \
   \( \
   thumbnail2.gif \
   -bordercolor white  -border 6 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 \
   -bordercolor none  -background  none \
   -rotate -8 \
   -trim +repage \
   \) \
   -gravity center \
   -composite \
   \
   \( \
   thumbnail3.gif \
   -bordercolor white  -border 6 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 \
   -bordercolor none  -background  none \
   -rotate 3 \
   -trim +repage \
   \) \
   -gravity center \
   -composite \
   \
   \( \
   thumbnail4.gif \
   -bordercolor white  -border 6 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 \
   -bordercolor none  -background  none \
   -rotate -17 \
   -trim +repage \
   \) \
   -gravity center \
   -composite \
   \
   -crop 200x160+0+0  +repage  -flatten  -trim +repage \
   -background black \( +clone -shadow 60x4+4+4 \) +swap \
   -background none  -flatten \
   \
   poloroid_stack.png
```

Comment: Actually, no they don't. They don't give a specific example for how to use multiple different images - they clone the original image. They also don't do a great job of explaining exactly what every option does in their examples - makes it very difficult for someone who has never used convert to work out just what the heck is going on without spending hours experimenting. It would be very helpful if you could take their example and expand on it to suit my needs specified above, explaining what the options do so I can adjust it to what I need.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Lindstrom - your solution didn't quite do what I needed, but it did put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I use Simpon Hampel Code with some change in this :

[How Margin Image with shadow in imagemagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340280/how-margin-image-with-shadow-in-imagemagick/26347849)

please check it..