# How Margin Image with shadow in imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, margin

I create an image with:
[Generate a stack of Polaroid-like photos from existing images using ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104187/generate-a-stack-of-polaroid-like-photos-from-existing-images-using-imagemagick)

```
convert \
img-5.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
-bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
-background none -rotate -4 \
\
\( img-2.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
   -background none -rotate 6 \
\) \
\
\( img-3.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
   -background none -rotate -2 \
\) \
\
\( img-1.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
   -background none -rotate -4 \
\) \
\
\( img-4.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
   -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
   -background none -rotate 4 \
\) \
\
-border 100x80 -gravity center +repage -flatten -trim +repage \
-background black \( +clone -shadow 60x4+4+4 \) +swap -background none \
-flatten stack.png
```

My Result: 
[image]

but i want to margin my result or padding from 4 side of background.

Is there any solution?
thank you

Comment: Can you please clarify what your are trying to achieve? Or show us. What is the exact problem?

Comment: Hi My Old Friend Mark :) , I use convert -size 500x500 xc:none gfx/gen/tmp.png to create transparent big file and composite my rotated images with that in center. i answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create picture Like This :

[image]

You need to use :

```
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none -background none -rotate 3 '.$pic01.'');
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none -background none -rotate -4 '.$pic02.'');
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none -background none -rotate 5 '.$pic03.'');
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none -background none -rotate -9 '.$pic04.'');

exec('convert -size 370x320 xc:none '.$result_image.'');
exec("composite -gravity center ".$pic01."  ".$result_image." -quality 100 ".$result_image); 
exec("composite -gravity center ".$pic02."  ".$result_image." -quality 100 ".$result_image);
exec("composite -gravity center ".$pic03."  ".$result_image." -quality 100 ".$result_image); 
exec("composite -gravity center ".$pic04."  ".$result_image." -quality 100 ".$result_image);

exec("convert ".$result_image." -background  black  ( +clone -shadow 100x3+0+0 ) +swap  -background  none   -flatten ".$result_image);
```

And your result will be like example.
don't forget if you need to more image or different images repeat :

```
exec('convert '.$newfile1.' -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none -background none -rotate 3 '.$pic01.'');
```

and change the $newfile or change $pic01 .... $pic(n)  if you need.
and compose it with $result_image like:

```
exec("composite -gravity center ".$pic(n)."  ".$result_image." -quality 100 ".$result_image);
```

I hope this use full.
best regard, thank you [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)